# Unity Animator - bool transitions keep re-entering state while true

Tags: unity, animation

My StateMachine is triggered in a loop as long as transition boolean is true.

I have made sure my code only runs once, where I set the animation bool:

```
animator.SetBool("talk", true);
```

This does trigger the transition but the problem is that it re-triggers every frame as long as the bool is true. I had the same issue with a normal state earlier, but there I could turn off "Can transition to self" which solved it.
However a StateMachine does not have that option.

I want the animation to play until the bool is set back to false, so using a trigger would not be good here.

[image]

EDIT: For some reason it seems the "Transition duration" is the one resetting my animation. So if I change that to 3, it re-enters every 3 seconds, and so on. This seems really weird?

How do I just make sure that the animation plays until its done, then it re-enters (to choose another random talking animation from my StateMachine), as long as `talk == true`?

Comment: As you set animation from "Any state" and also i think "Has end" is set to false. so every time when bool is true it restart the animation. so i would suggest to use trigger instead of bool. This is just my assumption.

Comment: @Swati I want the animation to loop several times until finished talking, so trigger wont really work.

Comment: then make sure to set "Has End" to true. and exit time to 1.

Comment: @Swati where are you getting "Has End" from?

Comment: sorry it is not "Has End" it is "Has Exit time" sorry my mistake.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help. If I activate exit time instead of checking for talk==false it behaves the same.

Comment: have you set the "Has Exit" to true and "Exit time" to 1.
Refter to "Transition properties" section on this page: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html

Answer (score 3):

In many cases, like working with a network game, you don't have the option of using trigger as it malfunctions over the network, so to solve this issue and continue using bool parameters, you just click on the transition, expand the Settings in the inspector and uncheck "Can Transition To Self".

[image: Uncheck this option]